# Fusion 5, Windows 8 and Boot Camp

Tags: bootcamp, vmware

VMware are not very direct about revealing the features of their producst.

[This KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1014618) claims that "VMware Fusion does not support launching a Boot Camp partition with Windows 8 installed on it" while the [Fusion 5 homepage](http://www.vmware.com/uk/products/desktop_virtualization/fusion/overview.html) says that Fusion 5 supports Windows 8 and that it "lets you run Windows and Mac applications side-by-side directly from your existing Boot Camp partition".

Any idea which is true? Does VMware Fusion 5 support Windows 8 Boot Camp installations or not?

And can it use a Windows 8 BC partition on another disk or only the first disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KB article appears to be outdated. A VMWare staff member advised that "[Windows 8 is fully supported as a Boot Camp virtual machine in VMware Fusion 5](http://communities.vmware.com/message/2102992#2102992)".

Comment: Yeah, I found that one last night too. I wished VMware would list the features of a product on the product's home page and not hidden away in forums.